# DBIx::Class: Counting entries with specific values in related table

Tags: mysql, perl, join, dbix-class

I have the two MySQL tables humans and dogs:

```
TABLE humans:
id int, name varchar(32)
TABLE dogs
id int, human int, dead int
```

Every human can have zero or more dogs. If the dog is dead, then the integer dead is set to "1". Now I want to count all humans who have (had) a dead dog.

In SQL this could be done with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM humans WHERE
    (SELECT count(*) FROM dogs WHERE humans.id = dogs.human AND dead = 1) > 0
```

How can I realize this with Perls great DBIx::Class?

Answer (score 0):

Solving this nicely with a subquery is hard because `SQL::Abstract` (which is used by DBIx::Class to build queries) assumes that you always have columns names in the elements of your `WHERE` clauses. You probably have to resort to literal SQL:

```
my $count = $schema->resultset('Humans')->count(
    \[ '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dogs WHERE human = me.id AND dead = 1) > 0' ]
);
```